# Set Up GWT Host Page

Tags: html, gwt

I need to set up a host page like the following:

[image]

The Blue div is the header.
The right div and the left div is the right sidebar and the left .
The bottom div is the footer.The red div the main body in which content will be displayed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [DockLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) to create the layout you describe. Check [GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels) on using LayoutPanels.

Comment: If you're not forced to using div's explicitly you should better go with the suggested DocklLayoutPanel (which is rendered as tables, but I hope this doesn't matter for you)

Comment: @chris DockLayoutPanel is *not* rendered as tables. It's rendered using absolutely positioned divs. Perhaps you are confusing things with HorizontalPanel and VerticalPanel.

Comment: The oldish DockPanel used tables for layout.

Comment: @Strelok: Don't know which way Dock LAYOUT Panel is rendered,  but my mistake was that I meant DockPanel which is rendered as tables which I would suggest